# iterating over values list in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I am looking to iterate over a Python dictionary where each key has a list of values, I am looking to either create a new list/dictionary where I have separated each value[x] or directly do stuff with the separated values.

here's a simplified example of the dictionary I have:

```
all_parameters = {"first": ["1a","1b","1c"], "second": ["2a","2b","2c"], "third": ["3a","3b","3c"]}
```

I am looking to separate the values like this (either by creating a new dictionary or list or directly doing stuff with the separated values).

```
grouped_parameters = [{"first": "1a", "second": "2a", "third": "3a"},
                      {"first": "1b", "second": "2b", "third": "3b"},
                      {"first": "1c", "second": "2c", "third": "3c"}]
```

I am insure how to iterate correctly over each key:value pair.

```
i = 0
for k, v in all_parameters.items():
    for item in v:
        # stuck here
    i+=1
```

Eventually the 'stuff' I am looking to do is convert each output (e.g. '{"first": "1a", "second": "2a", "third": "3a"}') into a string so that I can post each parameter group to a cell in a table, so ideally i'd prefer to do this dynamically instead of creating a new dictionary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will the value lists always be all the same length? If not, how do you want to handle short lists?

Comment: Also, bear in mind that items in a `dict` aren't ordered, so you need to be careful when converting a dict to a string if you want the fields to be in a certain order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a chance of the lists being of different length, you could use `map` with `None` like so:

```
all_parameters = {"first": ["1a", "1b", "1c", "1d"], "second": ["2a", "2b", "2c"], "third": ["3a", "3b", "3c"]}

final = [dict(zip(all_parameters.keys(), values)) for values in map(None, *all_parameters.values())]

print final
```

`map(None, *all_parameters.values())` gives you a tuple of the values for each key at each index - e.g. `('1a', '2a', '3a')`, and by zipping this to the keys and creating a dictionary, we get the required combination.

Note: this will only work in Python 2.x as `map` changed in 3.x. For Python 3.x we can use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

all_parameters = {"first": ["1a", "1b", "1c", "1d"], "second": ["2a", "2b", "2c"], "third": ["3a", "3b", "3c"]}

final = [dict(zip(all_parameters.keys(), values)) for values in zip_longest(*all_parameters.values())]

print(final)
```

In both cases we get:

```
[{'second': '2a', 'third': '3a', 'first': '1a'}, {'second': '2b', 'third': '3b', 'first': '1b'}, {'second': '2c', 'third': '3c', 'first': '1c'}, {'second': None, 'third': None, 'first': '1d'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all lists have the same length:

```
>>> length = len(next(all_parameters.itervalues()))
>>> [{k:v[i] for k,v in all_parameters.iteritems()} for i in range(length)]
[{'second': '2a', 'third': '3a', 'first': '1a'}, {'second': '2b', 'third': '3b', 'first': '1b'}, {'second': '2c', 'third': '3c', 'first': '1c'}]
```

In Python 3, use `len(next(iter(all_parameters.values())))` and `items` instead of `iteritems`.

(The iterator shenanigans are done because you don't need a list of all the dictionary values if you only want the length of an arbitrary value-list.)

Answer (score 1):

The items in a plain dict aren't ordered *, so you need to be careful when converting a dict to a string if you want the fields to be in a certain order.

This code uses a tuple containing the key strings in the order we want them to be in in the output dict strings.

```
all_parameters = {
    "first": ["1a","1b","1c"], 
    "second": ["2a","2b","2c"], 
    "third": ["3a","3b","3c"],
}

# We want keys to be in this order
all_keys = ("first", "second", "third")

# Assumes all value lists are the same length.
for t in zip(*(all_parameters[k] for k in all_keys)):
    a = ['"{}": "{}"'.format(u, v) for u, v in zip(all_keys, t)]
    print('{' + ', '.join(a) + '}')
```

**output**

```
{"first": "1a", "second": "2a", "third": "3a"}
{"first": "1b", "second": "2b", "third": "3b"}
{"first": "1c", "second": "2c", "third": "3c"}
```

#### How it works

We first use a generator expression `(all_parameters[k] for k in all_keys)` which yields the value lists from `all_parameters` in the order specified by `all_keys`. We pass those lists as args to `zip` using the `*` "splat" operator. So for your example data, it's equivalent to calling `zip` like this:

```
zip(["1a","1b","1c"], ["2a","2b","2c"], ["3a","3b","3c"])
```

`zip` effectively transposes the iterables you pass it, so the result of that call is an iterator that produces these tuples:

```
('1a', '2a', '3a'), ('1b', '2b', '3b'), ('1c', '2c', '3c')
```

We then loop over those tuples one by one, with the `for t in zip(...)`, so on the first loop `t` gets the value `('1a', '2a', '3a')`, then `('1b', '2b', '3b')`, etc.

Next we have a list comprehension that zips the value strings up with the corresponding key string and formats them into a string with double-quotes around each key and value string. We then join those strings together with commas and spaces as separators (and add brace characters) to make our final dict strings.

---

* Actually in Python 3.6 plain dicts *do* retain insertion order, but that is currently an implementation detail, and it should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but

```
for i in range(len(all_parameters['first'])):
     for position in all_parameters:
         print(position+" "+all_parameters[position][i])
```

gives an output like this

> first 1a
>   second 2a
>   third 3a
>   first 1b
>   second 2b
>   third 3b
>   first 1c
>   second 2c
>   third 3c

This will work only if each dictionary element has a list the same size as the first one.